# AS3 hitTestObject is not working

Tags: actionscript-3

I was making flash that  moving a circle on my keyboard and creating a flash that hit the wall.
But method 'hitTestObject' is not working...

Hou to solve this ploblem?

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,atKeydown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,atKeyup);

function atKeydown(e :KeyboardEvent) :void
{
    if(e.keyCode == 38) stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterYUp);
    if(e.keyCode == 40) stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterYDown);
    if(e.keyCode == 37) stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterXLeft);
    if(e.keyCode == 39) stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterXRight);
}

function atKeyup(e :KeyboardEvent) :void
{
    if(e.keyCode == 38) stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterYUp);
    if(e.keyCode == 40) stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterYDown);
    if(e.keyCode == 37) stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterXLeft);
    if(e.keyCode == 39) stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterXRight);
}

function enterYUp(e :Event) :void
{
    ball.y -= 10;
}
function enterYDown(e :Event) :void
{
    ball.y += 10;
}
function enterXLeft(e :Event) :void
{
    ball.x -= 10;
}
function enterXRight(e :Event) :void
{
    ball.x += 10;
}

if(ball.hitTestObject(wall) == true) trace("!!!!");
```

Comment: The line with **hitTest** is outside of any event handler so it is executed only once: on app start. Then you just move ball without checking anything. It doesn't work this way, ofc. In order to make it work, you need to check for **hitTest** every time you move the ball.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function enterYUp(e :Event) :void
{
 var bool = checkHit("y", -10); // each frame checks for a hit, returns a Boolean (see the function below)
 carryOut(bool, "y", -10); // the movement is carried out based on the Boolean
}
function enterYDown(e :Event) :void
{
var bool = checkHit("y", +10); // you can send the "y" property, and where it wants to go.
 carryOut(bool, "y", +10);
}
function enterXLeft(e :Event) :void
{
var bool = checkHit("x", -10);
 carryOut(bool, "x", -10);
}
function enterXRight(e :Event) :void
{
 var bool = checkHit("x", +10);
 carryOut(bool, "x", -10);
}

function checkHit(_prop, _num):Boolean
{ 
 // This single function will run every frame, comparing the balls 'predicted position' 
  if((ball[_prop] + _num) <=  _numCheck)
  {
  // i might use hitTestPoint instead, but I hate using hitTestObject... it can act weird sometimes.
  return true;
  }
  else
  {
  return false;
  }
}


function carryOut(bool, _prop,_num):void
{
  if(bool)
 {
  trace("hit");
 }
 else
 {
  // if the Boolean returned false
  // ball[_prop] is ball.x or ball.y depending on if you sent "x" or "y".
  // it will ADD the _num you sent, so adding -10 is the same as subtracting.
  ball[_prop] += _num;
 }
}
```

Comment: Although it was accepted, this answer is lacking severely: the code is badly formatted as well as shows the poor understanding of basic data types, the whole answer misses the point of the problem, and on top of that you advise not to use **hitTest** just because **YOU** have seen it do things beyond your knowledge and skill.